# Function to get href of link at mouse location/on hover (Something similar to Copy Link Location in Chromium)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the href of the currently hovered link using JavaScript in order to open that link in a new tab.

I could fetch the href of the current page using:

```
var myLink = window.location.href;
```

and then call:

```
window.open(myLink);
```

But I would like to call some JavaScript function that returns the link of the element under the mouse (Just like how Right-Clicking and then choosing **Copy Link Location** works in Chromium or Firefox browsers).

**EDIT**:
Well I tried this:

```
(function(){
    var list = document.querySelectorAll( 'a' );
    var myString = "myString_Default_Value";
    for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i ++)
      list.item(i).onmouseover = function() { myString = this.href; };
    return myString;
})();
```

Reason why I did this is because I am passing the outer anonymous method as a string from my .NET application (don't worry, I escaped the double quotes in my code) and then getting a callback with the JS result (in this case it's a string result).

Unfortunately in my application I keep getting the default value of **myString**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you need to open it in a new tab with javascript? You can just set the `target` attribute to `_blank` on the link. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: I am calling JS functions from my .NET app to view web pages. I need to support a functionality just like "**Copy Link Location**" after determining the href of the link under the mouse (whether it was a button, image, normal link,etc...) so I can open that link in a new tab. (Pretty much trying to implement "**Open in New Tab**")

Comment: Regarding your edit: the `return myString` executes immediately after installing the handlers; there's hardly any time for a user to mouseover a link. How are you wanting to provide the user with the 'Open in new tab' option? Maybe a tooltip?

Comment: well I changed the logic a bit; I am storing *this.href* in a global variable. So when I access it then that would be the "lastly hovered" item that has <a> property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is opening some links in a new tab, just add `target="_blank"` (or `target="_new"`) to any link you want in a new tab.

```
//[].forEach.call allows calling .forEach on array-like objects.
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(link) {
    if (shouldBeInNewTab(link.href)) { link.target = "_blank"; }
});
```

---

What you normally do, is add event listeners to all links on the page, like so:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(link) {
    link.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
        console.log(this.href); // `this` being the element triggering the event.
    });
});
```

But this has disadvantages:

- It's wasteful, if you have 5000 links on the page, you'd have to loop 5000 items, and add an event listener on each.
- It won't work for new DOM nodes. If you add a link with JavaScript, it won't report its href when hovered.

So we can solve this with **event delegation**, basically, I add a listener on a common ancestor (in this case, `document`), and filter for items on the inside.

```
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    var hoveredEl = event.target; // The actual element which was hovered.
    if (hoveredEl.tagName !== 'A') { return; } // Ignore non links
    console.log(hoveredEl.href); // Do what we want here!
});
```

Comment: your **event delegation** method is just gold! And is pretty much what I am after. It is true that looping over +5k links is a waste (I am doing this only once when the page has finished loading) But with your method, I can do this when I start loading the website without worrying about the number of references. (nor waiting till the page finishes loading)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jQuery like this:

```js
$('a').on('mouseover', function(){ console.log( this.href ) } )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
  <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the JS without jQuery:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll( "a" );
for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i ++)
  list.item(i).onmouseover = function() { console.log(this.href ) };
```

Comment: Dude... this is just magnificent! Thanks for adding a non-jQuery answer :) some people just provide jQuery answers not knowing that you're executing and getting JS callbacks from a native/.NET environment and have no control over the web server/not developing an actual site but building plugins/a browser xD

Gonna give this a try and inform you if it succeded, with a minor edit; inside the anonymous function in the loop I am going to fill an array and pass it back to my .NET app.

Comment: Due to comment section usage of "mini-markdown" formatting... I have to post my comment with the code as an answer. Please do check it out @Kenney

Comment: The jQuery answer is irrelevant, and the non-jQuery one is broken.

Comment: @Madara the non-jQuery answer is working though :P I mean with some adjustments (I am using AddListener as you suggested :) ) ((well it didn't feel right to reset the listeners to null and assign the new one anyways lol))

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

HTML:

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://www.google.es">Click here</a>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector("#myLink").onmouseover = function(){
    window.open(this);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3rb10xf0/

EDIT: OK, this doesn't answer the question, anyway I'm keeping it here by OP's petition.

Comment: Thank you so much for your initiative Neo :) 

Sadly, I am trying to achieve something dynamic. I am not creating a web page but rather a browser that interprets the webpage's data using a C++ engine and JS functions.